# paper trail plugin and rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I have a model, `Car`.

When I update an instance of `Car` through a form in my application, the [PaperTrail plugin](http://airbladesoftware.com/tags/papertrail) is called and a new version is created.

But if I test this model using rspec, the PaperTrail plugin is never called. Why not?

Answer (score 3):

How are you creating the objects? I found that when I created them through a factory, a papertail version was not created. But when I created them through ActiveRecord (e.g. Car.create(params)) a paptertrail version was created

Answer (score 3):

First of all check this:

```
# in config/environments/test.rb
config.after_initialize do
  PaperTrail.enabled = false
end
```

read this [manual](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#turning-papertrail-offon)  or try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2658418)